# total variation of a measure

Tags: analysis

I ran across this question in my analysis textbook.  I just cannot prove this.

Suppose $\mu$ is a complex measure on $X$ such that $\mu(X)=1$ and $|\mu|(X)=1$.  Show $\mu$ is a positive real measure.

Answer (score 2):

Take some measurable set $A$. Then 
$$\mu(A)+\mu(X\setminus A)=\mu(X)=1$$ while 
$$1\leq|\mu(A)|+|\mu(X\setminus A)|\leq|\mu|(X)=1$$
Now use the fact that for any two complex numbers $z,z'$, $|z+z'|\leq|z|+|z'|$ with equality iff $z$ and $z'$ are positively collinear.

Comment: what does positively collinear mean?

Comment: It means that there is a positive real number $\lambda>0$ such that $z'=\lambda z$ (or $z=\lambda z'$.)

Comment: @john Has this helped you at all? Do you want me to finish the argument?